# Menu Flyout using YUI or Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, yui

I would like to create a flyout menu exactly like how it is on Walmart.com. Could somebody help me with this.

Comment: What aspect of this do you need help with exactly? We are certainly not going to write the whole thing for you...

Answer (score 0):

Well here is something to start you off, you could modify this to be vertical, it makes use of jQuery.

http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/mega-drop-downs-w-css-jquery/